# How to compare data by month with another year in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, report

I have one table sales order with struct:

```
- ItemID
- Customer
- Year
- Month
- Quantity
```

I want build report like:

```
Customer | Item  | Year | Month | Quantity | The same month of the previous year quantity|
```

Could you please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need to do a self join. Could you provide one or two example rows and the output you'd like to have?

Comment: MS SQL and MySQL both has LEAD and LAG function, and that will solve your problem https://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/  and https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Can you clarify which RDBMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing a `SELF JOIN` and joining on the previous year:

```
SELECT 
T1.Customer,
T1.Item,
T1.Year,
T1.Month,
T1.Quantity,
T2.Quantity AS Last_year_quantity
FROM Table AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table AS T2 ON T1.Customer=T2.Customer 
AND T1.Item=T2.Item
AND (T1.Year-1)=T2.Year
AND T1.Month=T2.Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick mockup with no table structure or anything

```
select a.customer, a.item, a.year, a.month, a.quantity,
  (select b.quantity 
     from table_name b 
    where b.customer = a.customer
      and b.item = a.item
      and b.month = a.month
      and b.year = a.year - 1) as prev_year_qty
from table_name a
```

Comment: Hi everybody, i'm using UNION ALL and it work well. Thanks